# CDK Reading From Vault

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-ssm, vault

In Terraform can read the values from Vault (stored in AWS SSM as secure strings). However, with CDK we have to put it in SSM or secrets manager and read the value in CDK. Is there a way CDK can read from the Vault?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible using [AWS Custom Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html). AWS CDK provides a way to create custom resources that respond to CloudFormation's CRUD events (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/custom-resources-readme.html).

According to the AWS Custom Resource docs, "return values are defined by the custom resource provider, and are retrieved by calling Fn::GetAtt on the provider-defined attributes". So after creating a custom resource that returns your Hashicorp Vault key as an attribute, you can have another resource reference that value using [Fn::GetAtt in CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.Fn.html#static-getwbrattlogicalnameofresource-attributename), and the value should not get publicly exposed in the CloudFormation template.

Another alternative could be to sync secret values between Hashicorp Vault and AWS SSM/SecretsManager.